# Remove previous <select><option> when select new with appendChild

Tags: jquery, appendchild, createelement

When click to `<li>` i'm getting information from database to json.

"55,63" is data from json.

**Code:**

```
$('li.channel').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var numbers = "55,63";
        var number = numbers.split(',');
        var select = document.getElementById('selectElement');
        for (f = 1; f < (countdata); f++){
            q = description(f);
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = number[f];
            opt.innerHTML = q;
            select.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }, 5000);
});
<select id="selectElement"></select>
```

**Result:**

```
<select id="selectElementId">
 <option value="55">effects - Russian</option>
 <option value="63">effects - English</option>
</select>
```

Next, when i click to another `<li>`, i'm getting new data to json.

I want to remove all previous `<option>` elements and get new `<option>` with new 'Numbers'.
But when i click to another `<li>`, my `<select>` element getting update:

```
<select id="selectElementId">
 <option value="55">effects - Russian</option>
 <option value="63">effects - English</option>
 <option value="203">clean - Latvian</option>
 <option value="207">clean - English</option>
</select>
```

**How to remove previous data using jQuery / javascript?**

Comment: Number is a variable type in javascript, don't use it as a variable name like that.

Comment: Ok, it's just sample! My variables are in diferent names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `empty()` you can just do:

```
$('li.channel').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var numbers = "55,63";
        var number = numbers.split(',');
        var select = document.getElementById('selectElement');
        $(select).empty(); //empty the select
        for (f = 1; f < (countdata); f++){
            q = description(f);
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = number[f];
            opt.innerHTML = q;
            select.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)